# How to assign 3 diffrent values in a variable (1200 occurence)

Tags: r, dataset, analytics

I have a varible like this

```
NewDate
02-11-2021
02-11-2021
02-11-2021
02-11-2021
02-11-2021
02-11-2021
02-11-2021
```

I want it to look like this

```
NewDate
02-11-2021
09-10-2009
05-05-2011
02-11-2021
09-10-2009
05-05-2011
...(1200 times)
```

Comment: If your problem got solved please [choose an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
insertDates<- c("09-10-2009", "05-05-2011")
c(sapply(df1$NewDate, function(x) {c(x,insertDates)}))
```

to get something that looks more like your end result:

```
data.frame(NewDate = c(sapply(df1$NewDate, function(x) {c(x,insertDates)})), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

---

data:

```
df1<-
structure(list(NewDate = c("02-11-2021", "02-11-2021", "02-11-2021", 
"02-11-2021", "02-11-2021", "02-11-2021", "02-11-2021")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can u suggest me a fucntion like porps or something that assigns random values to this variable

Comment: @LakhanSinghRajput unclear what you want. EDIT you question and add new content please.

Answer (score 1):

You can split by each line, `rbind` a new data frame with the requested dates, and `rbind` the whole list, i.e.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dd, seq(nrow(dd))), 
                  function(i) {i <- rbind(i, 
                                   data.frame(NewDate = c("09-10-2009", "05-05-2011"), 
                                                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)); i}))
```